# Euclidian distance VBA (Transpose function in VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm triying to create a fuction that calculates distance between 2 points but when I use mmult and transpose functions I get an error whereas i use sumpriduct function it works perfectly but I just want to understand why

Could you hlp me?

```
Function distancia(RangoA As Range, RangoB As Range) As Long
 Dim s() As Variant
 Dim t() As Variant
 Dim r() As Variant
  s = RangoA
  t = RangoB
  ReDim r(UBound(s), 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(s)
   r(i, 1) = s(i, 1) - t(i, 1)
Next i
 distancia = Application.MMult(r, Application.Transpose(r))


End Function
```

Comment: Probably because you are going to get an array function, are you entering it as array formula -with the brackets-?

Comment: Yes, what I did to solve it was to use VarType() function and I noticed when using mmult, it is returned a matrix data type, so I was unable to apply squared root or any other transformation, so I simply sum my matrix and then I could apply squared root. Of course this equivalent to use sumproduct().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that an array created from a range is always 2D, if you transpose it the array is still 2D. E.g. first it was 20x1 after transpose it is 1x20. You should pass the values from the array as from a 2D array, thus;

```
Application.Transpose(r)(1)
```

Comment: Actually i have considered what you are saying but i did not work:

`distancia = Application.MMult(r, Application.Transpose(r)) ^ (1 / 2)`

Comment: I can handle this issue by working directly with my range instead of assainging it to a matrix i mean by looping rangoA(i,j) rather than x=rangoA